# Is it possible to create thread-safe collections without locks?

Tags: algorithm, multithreading, language-agnostic

This is pure just for interest question, any sort of questions are welcome.

So is it possible to create thread-safe collections without any locks? By locks I mean any thread synchronization mechanisms, including Mutex, Semaphore, and even Interlocked, all of them. Is it possible at user level, without calling system functions? Ok, may be implementation is not effective, i am interested in theoretical possibility. If not what is the minimum means to do it?

**EDIT:** Why immutable collections don't work.

This of class `Stack` with methods `Add` that returns another Stack.

Now here is program:

```
Stack stack = new ...;

ThreadedMethod()
{
   loop
   {
      //Do the loop
      stack = stack.Add(element);
   }
}
```

this expression `stack = stack.Add(element)` is not atomic, and you can overwrite new stack from other thread.

Thanks,
Andrey

Comment: Whenever someone asks me "can you do X?" my standard reply is that we can do anything you want given enough time, resources and money.

Comment: @Jesse C. Slicer: Can you write algorithm that will take a look at another algorithm and input data and tell will this program stop or not? no, you can't, it is fundamentally impossible. I am speaking here of theoretical possibility.

Comment: @Jesse C. Slicer: Interesting. Can you even produce a planar drawing of the K5 graph?

Comment: I was attempting to inject a bit of humor, sorry to have ruffled feathers.

Comment: I guess that kind of humor is risky business in a field ridden with impossibility results (both CS in general, and concurrency in particular) :)

Comment: Ok since you didn't want interlocks either then this reallyfalls in the theoretical realm. Herlihy defines something called the consensus number of a structure , which indicates how many processors can access the structure consistently. He then uses this number to prove the non existence of algorithms implementing this structure using a fixed set of instructions.  He proved that stacks cannot be implemented just with read-modify-write instructions only for example. So this should answer your question.

Comment: `stack = stack.Add(element) is not atomic, and you can overwrite new stack from other thread` -- that's right, but if you're writing code like that then you're doing it wrong, its not an idiom you should be using with immutable data structures. Typically two threads share data using message passing concurrency, and if two threads are updating their own copy of a data structure than you should have an additional step to merge both objects when your process finishes.

Comment: @Juliet you guide yourself to pitfall. "message passing" pattern itself need some synchronization. i think Il-Bhima explained very clearly why we can't live without locking mechanisms and atomic operations.

Comment: @Andrey: not to be too pedant, but it really depends on whether your question is more theoretical or practical. From a theoretical standpoint, even message passing uses low-level locks to queue messages, and in that respect you can say "well I guess you can't update atomically without locks". But from a practical point of view, like the type of code you write with immutable data structures and a decent message passing system, the synchronization is totally transparent, you just wouldn't have locks in your client code.

Comment: @Juliet question was 110% theoretical. Of course libraries that deal with multithreading use locks/atomic. the question was can we deal without them somehow. Question was not how to avoid locks in just **your** code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There seem to be misconceptions by even guru software developers about what constitutes a lock.

One has to make a distinction between atomic operations and locks.  Atomic operations like  compare and swap perform an operation (which would otherwise require two or more instructions) as a single uninterruptible instruction.  Locks are built from atomic operations however they can result in threads busy-waiting or sleeping until the lock is unlocked.

In most cases if you manage to implement an parallel algorithm with atomic operations without resorting to locking you will find that it will be orders of magnitude faster.  This is why there is so much interest in wait-free and lock-free algorithms.

There has been a ton of research done on implementing various wait-free data-structures. While the code tends to be short, they can be notoriously hard to prove that they really work due to the subtle race conditions that arise.  Debugging is also a nightmare.  However a lot of work has been done and you can find wait-free/lock-free hashmaps, queues (Michael Scott's lock free queue),  stacks, lists, trees, the list goes on.  If you're lucky you'll also find some open-source implementations.

Just google 'lock-free my-data-structure' and see what you get.

For further reading on this interesting subject start from [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Art-Multiprocessor-Programming-Maurice-Herlihy/dp/0123705916) by Maurice Herlihy.

Comment: take a look at answer by Strilanc

Comment: Petersen's lock is a spin lock.  You asked for algorithms without locking.  You may very well find that the Semaphore and Mutex implementation in your language of choice is based on Peterson's.

Algorithms are locking if they can postpone indefinitely the execution of a thread.  Algorithms are non-blocking otherwise.  Lock-free and wait-free add further restrictions.

Comment: If you feel Strilanc's reply answers your question better then you can change the accepted answer, don't worry :-)

Comment: under what conditions CAS operations is better and worst than lock based operations in multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, immutable collections! :)

Comment: i thought of that and tried to create one, but failed. You still have pointer/reference to this collection shared and while you add elements someone can override the reference.

Comment: @Andrey: You can't add elements to an immutable collection.

Comment: @Uri - adding element produce new collection. Once you did it you have to share the pointer with other threads. then see your answer :)

Comment: "Override the reference": what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Uri @Matti Virkkunen you can create new collection with n+1 element. check editted question.

Comment: @Andrey, oh, "overwrite" the reference. Well, you implicitly make the (mutable) pointer part of the collection, the combined structure is certainly not immutable then.

Comment: @Andrey: Even in that case the collection itself is quite thread safe. However, your reference to it isn't.

Comment: @Dimitris Andreou pointer to collection is not part of collection. but overall setting is not thread safe, right

Comment: Yes, I meant the same, the composition of the collection with the extra (mutable) pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to do concurrency without any support from the system. You can use [Peterson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) or the more general [bakery algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm) to emulate a lock.

Comment: does it rely on atomic instructions?

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, this algorithm is very interesting

Comment: @Andrey It doesn't use any special instructions.

Comment: people here explained that it is not possible, i believed them and now i don't know what to think :)

Comment: The reason they said it's impossible is because the bakery algorithm is typically considered a 'lock'. You phrased your question poorly but I guessed at what you meant.

Comment: You link to Peterson's algorithm says it does not work on multiprocessor systems that reorder memory accesses.

Comment: @daniel Inserting memory barriers at certain places would make it work on multiprocessor systems. But you're correct that, if the cpu re-orders some of the instructions, it stops working correctly.

Comment: @Strilanc by lock i meant something low level, something that calls operating system.

Comment: Would any of you actually use these algorithms? They are very interesting though for sure.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on how you define the term (as other commenters have discussed) but yes, it's possible for *many* data structures, at least, to be implemented in a non-blocking way (without the use of traditional mutual-exclusion locks).

I strongly recommend, if you're interested in the topic, that you read [the blog of Cliff Click](http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff-click/) -- Cliff is the head guru at Azul Systems, who produce hardware + a custom JVM to run Java systems on massive and massively parallel (think up to around 1000 cores and in the hundreds of gigabytes of RAM area), and obviously in those kinds of systems locking can be death (disclaimer: not an employee or customer of Azul, just an admirer of their work).

Dr Click has famously come up with a non-blocking HashTable, which is basically a complex (but quite brilliant) state machine using atomic CompareAndSwap operations.

There is a two-part blog post describing the algorithm ([part one](http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff-click/2007-03-26-non-blocking-hashtable), [part two](http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff-click/2007-04-01-non-blocking-hashtable-part-2)) as well as a talk given at Google ([slides](http://www.azulsystems.com/events/javaone_2007/index.htm), [video](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=2139967204534450862)) -- the latter in particular is a fantastic introduction. Took me a few goes to 'get' it -- it's complex, let's face it! -- but if you presevere (or if you're smarter than me in the first place!) you'll find it very rewarding.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.
The problem is that at some point you will need some mutual exclusion primitive (perhaps at the machine level) such as an atomic test-and-set operation. Otherwise, you could always devise a race condition. Once you have a test-and-set, you essentially have a lock.

That being said, in older hardware that did not have any support for this in the instruction set, you could disable interrupts and thus prevent another "process" from taking over but effectively constantly putting the system into a serialized mode and forcing sort of a mutual exclusion for a while.

Comment: you might be right. do you speak from your view or there is some kind of proof of that?

Comment: Vague recollection from college. I am sure most textbooks discuss this exact question. The point is that you always need a way to do mutual exclusion. To do that, you need support from your hardware and way to access that support from your language.

Comment: I don't agree.  test-and-set is not "essentially a lock".

Comment: @Il-Bhima it falls into my definition of lock in this question (Interlocked)

Comment: take a look at answer by Strilanc

Answer (score 1):

At the very least you need atomic operations. There are lock free algorithms for single cpu's. I'm not sure about multiple CPU's

Comment: take a look at answer by Strilanc